# import wizard creating duplicate contacts and accounts

Tags: data-import-wizard, data-import

When I am trying to import accounts with contacts using import wizard,I am having duplicate contacts imported.I am using Match account by :Account Name and Account Site to map and using owner id to import.

Please help

Comment: are you adding new records or updating records?

Comment: show your csv file

Answer (score 0):

Since contacts are getting duplicate you might have selected match contact by name which you can change to match contact by email (since email would be unique over names).[image]
Please find attachment for reference.

As a common practice mark this as solution if this solves your problem.